# Op-amp offset and multiplication

Tags: operational-amplifier

i have a DC signal from some kind of measurement, that changes from 1.75V to 5V. I need to process it, so that it changes from -5V to 1.5V. See table:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/LEUexTQ.png]

So basically I need to **subtract from input 4.25V** (or add -4.25 offset) **and then multiply it by 2**.

A have two power supplies: -15V and +15V.

I'd also like to be able to make some adjustments to offset adding (+- 0.5V) by some kind of trimmer.

Is it possible to do in using only one op-amp? What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Thanks,

Comment: The search term you're looking for is difference amp.

Comment: A question - how accurate and stable are your +/- 15 volt supplies?

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with a single ended input signal you could do it with a fully differential op amp. The simpler ones have a fully diff output, i.e. the output is not referenced to ground but is the difference between two terminals. You build the usual non inverting amp with the inputs and the positive output, and feed \$-4.25\$V to the negative output. This *might* work but not all op amps like an output to be set to a specific voltage.

If you can use an instrumentation amplifier that would be much better. It is not an opamp but it is a single component. INAMPS need no external feedback, that's built in, and they usually have some very precise preset gain, or you can set it eithger with a control voltage or digitally. The output usually have a reference terminal: that is where you want to hook your \$-4.25\$V, and that terminal is though exactly for this purpose.

To vary the offset you can set the ref voltage with a potentiometer, maybe add some safety resistors in order to not let the ref terminal swing the full \$\pm 15\$V: the inamp might not like it as well as your subsequent circuit.

As hinted in the comments, if your supplies are not well regulated using a mere divider to get the \$-4.25\$V won't work: you will need a linear regulator and a divider after that.

If you absolutely need to do that with a single ended, single op amp there is a circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fU4Icl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Some analysis leads to:
$$
V_{out} = \left(1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{R_3+R_4}\left(V_sR_4+ER_3\right) 
$$
that is in the form \$V_{out}=\alpha V_s + \beta E\$ with \$\alpha\$ and \$\beta\$ positive.

Just work out some values for the resistors if you want to build this last circuit, but the INAMP solution is the best you can get.

**pros and cons** of each solution:

**INAMP** pros: it's designed to do what you want, your only concern is the offset voltage but that is a concern for every solution. cons: costs and power consumption.

**FULLY DIFF AMP** pros: it's easy and cheap to set up, costs and power are just like a single ended opamp. cons: it probably won't work since you try to set one of the output rails to a fixed voltage

**SINGLE OPAMP** pros: dirty cheap and easy, fits the spec. cons: do you see that ton of resistors? they are bad. they are not precise, they need space, they are bad creatures. Plus \$\alpha\$ and \$\beta\$ are somewhat connected, i.e. you can't vary one of them leaving the other untouched if you act on a single component.

Comment: You haven't explained why the diffamp and inamp solutions are superior to the (quite straightforward) single opamp solution.

Comment: oh man there's a ton on reasons, I'm liable to forget half of them. wouldn't you just trust me? :P

Comment: The answer's pretty useless if you don't explain what conditions you'd use each possible solution in. The section you added at the end makes your answer a whole lot better.

Comment: I have added some insights but I think that explaining all the conditions is beyond the question and the scope of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to do this with one op-amp but the offset adjust will tend to modify the gain. Here's a simple dual op-amp solution.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0UdF1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R5 = (Vref/4.25V) * 20K

If you use the positive supply for Vref you'd need a 70.6K resistor (69.8K is a standard value).

If you used a quad op-amp you could use one of the additional amplifiers to buffer the input (just a voltage follower, no other parts) and another with two resistors to invert Vref (pot goes from Vref to -Vref) so that you would have a more stable offset adjustment. R3 value would be adjusted downward to maintain the gain.